# Post created using create image share API with /ugcPosts endpoint is not visible on linkedin on my timeline

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I have implemented all three steps for sharing an image post on linkedin using create image share api described below. But created posts are not visible on my linkedin feed/posts or recent activities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share

First time I created the post is visible using API and it returned `{"id":"urn:li:share:6521244543193575424"}`

Posted Visible post url:
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:6520269375554060288/

Second time onwards created with same code below returns similar response with created post id and with 201 created status code but post is not visible on linkedin.

For example this post
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:6521027773560119296

I checked my linkedin profile  but couldn't find my posts any where.

Code for Final function for posting I am using(3rd step for creating image share using the documentation link above) :

```
 def share_on_linkedin(self, asset, title, description):
    # asset = "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5122AQEAatG9rZ7MhQ"

    headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
    payload = {
        "author": "urn:li:person:leRbOTCFKK",
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": description
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "status": "READY",
                        "description": {
                            "text": "Center stage!"
                        },
                        "media": asset,
                        "title": {
                            "text": title
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
        }
    }

    try:
        data = json.dumps(payload, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts"
        response = requests.post(url , headers=headers, data=data )
        print response.text

        result = json.loads(response.text)  
        if response.status_code==200 or response.status_code==201:
            print response.text
            print response.headers              
            posted_url =  "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/"+result['id']
                            print posted_url 
            return True, posted_url
        return False, None

    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Output:

```
{"id":"urn:li:share:6521245116978552832"}
{'Content-Length': '41', 'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0', 'X-Li-Pop': 'prod-tmu1', 'X-LI-ResponseOrigin': 'RGW', 'X-RestLi-Id': 'urn:li:share:6521245116978552832', 'X-LI-UUID': 'aKr30Z+1kxWAo4kEzioAAA==', 'X-LI-Route-Key': '"b=SB83:g=115:u=3:i=1554785994:t=1554872227:s=AQH26er48VUD_YiXQIgAqujebI53eswQ"', 'X-Li-Fabric': 'prod-lsg1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Location': '/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A6521245116978552832', 'Set-Cookie': 'lidc="b=SB83:g=115:u=3:i=1554785994:t=1554872227:s=AQH26er48VUD_YiXQIgAqujebI53eswQ"', 'Date': 'Tue, 09 Apr 2019 04:59:55 GMT', 'X-LI-Proto': 'http/1.1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Posted url constructed from above successful response is:
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:6521245116978552832

But this post is not visible.

Can anybody help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to verify your media asset is available and ready to be posted before submitting your ugcPosts request.

After you've uploaded your image binary, submit a request to the /assets API and check the status is **AVAILABLE**

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/C5122AQEAatG9rZ7MhQ`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. GET api on /assets give Ok(200) status code with following response.
`u'{"serviceRelationships":[{"identifier":"urn:li:userGeneratedContent","relationshipType":"OWNER"}],"recipes":[{"recipe":"urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image","status":"CLIENT_ERROR"}],"mediaTypeFamily":"STILLIMAGE","created":1554873463315,"lastModified":1554873468185,"id":"C5122AQEPLd4qViROFg","status":"ALLOWED"}'
`

Comment: After that /assets checking availability called /ugsPosts and it also return 200 status code with posted id `{"id":"urn:li:share:6521613997417037824"}
`
But still posted url done through /ugcPosts is not visible....
Posted URL:
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:6521613997417037824/

Comment: Is there anything else we can about it?

Comment: Within the response body you pasted, the status is shown as `CLIENT_ERROR`. You need to verify the image has uploaded successfully before creating your ugcPost.

Comment: If you're getting `CLIENT_ERROR`, double-check that you're providing the correct `Content-Type` header when you upload the file.

Comment: @rinogo I have tried everything, im even specifying content type, but still i get CLIENT_ERROR on some images. What could be the reason?

Comment: @SHAHRUKHSHAHID One thing that helped me was to start with the examples provided by LinkedIn and to get them working in cURL and Postman. Once I had them working in those tools, I changed fields one by one in Postman and uploaded via my app instead of cURL. In other words, start from a "known working" approach and change things one by one until they break. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Any solution in end for this. I am also facing the same issue here. The response is coming 200 but the image is not appearing in Linkedin

Comment: @rinogo what is the correct Content-Type and which API I have to set Content-Type?

Comment: Same issue here, image uploads just fine but issue is for VIDEO only  .. 
headers are right, getting 200 but when checking asset status , shows  CLIENT_ERROR .. anyone having solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

## Use python to share text and image on LinkedIn API

## Python Linkedin, How to share content on user's wall

i#mage upload linkedin api

## code start from here

```
 def imageShare(request):

if request.FILES.getlist('media') and request.POST['postText']:
    # step 1
    try:
        new_asset.clear()

    except:
        pass
    access_token = token[0]
    h = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(access_token),

        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',

    }

    data = {
        "registerUploadRequest": {
            "recipes": [
                "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image"
            ],
            "owner": "urn:li:person:mUIlTwceuD",
            "serviceRelationships": [
                {
                    "relationshipType": "OWNER",
                    "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    z = requests.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload', headers=h, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(z.text)
    aa = z.json()['value']['uploadMechanism']['com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest'][
        'uploadUrl']
    shareurl.append(aa)
    # print(shareurl)
    bb = z.json()['value']['asset']
    asset = bb.replace('urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:', '')
    new_asset.append(asset)

    # step 2 upload binary image

    upload_url = str(aa)
    postText = request.POST['postText']
    image = request.FILES.getlist('media')
    print('blank image', image)

    for i in image:
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(access_token),
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',

        }
        response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=i.read())

    he = {

        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(access_token),
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

    }

    ab = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/' + str(new_asset[0]), headers=he)
    print('submittttttttt', ab.content)
    #     return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/social_app/index/')
    #
    #
    #
    # def index(request):
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(access_token),
    }
    data = {
        "author": "urn:li:person:mUIlTwceuD",
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": postText
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "status": "READY",
                        "description": {
                            "text": "Center stage!"
                        },
                        "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:" + str(new_asset[0]),
                        "title": {
                            "text": "LinkedIn Talent Connect 2018"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
        }
    }

    z = requests.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(z.text)
    return HttpResponse('Image shared')
else:
if request.method == 'POST':
    post = request.POST['postText']
    print("post = ", post)
    sub = {
        "author": "urn:li:person:mUIlTwceuD",
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": post,
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
            }
        },

        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
        }
    }

    h = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(access_token),
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',

    }
    a = requests.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts', headers=h, data=json.dumps(sub))
    print(a, a.content, a.text, a.json())
return render(request, 'post.html', {})

return HttpResponse('text sent')
```

Comment: This does not work... can you share a working one please.